# Программа на питоне ест много памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, ram

Сижу такой, пишу многопоточную программу и тут бац - она жрёт память в арифметической прогрессии... Я думаю, что после исполнения потока в памяти остаётся мусор, как лучше его убрать из моего кода?

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    while True:
        try:
            if not a in base:
                br = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser')
                br.open(a)
                form = br.get_forms()[0]
                form["x"].value = 'mytext'
                form["y"].value = b
                br.submit_form(form)
                if "yes" in br.url:
                    base.append(a)
                    valid.append([a,b])
                    break
                break
           else:
                break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()

base = []
valid = []
af = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
bf = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=int(sys.argv[3])) as executor:
    for bb in bf:
        for aa in af:
            executor.submit(myfunc, aa.strip(), bb.strip())
        af.seek(0)

af.close()
bf.close()
```

Comment: `while(true):`? Как оно работает если `while True:` правильно? Еще нет информации о количестве потоков. Если потоков очень много, можно попробовать делать запросы по сети через асинхронность. Кст, используете питон 2 или 3?

Comment: Да, извините, вы правы. Python3, потоков порядка 100-300. Мои догадки насчёт мусора имеют смысл быть? Можете пояснить, как асинхронные запросы реализовать?

Comment: А вам точно столько потоков нужно? Посмотрите этот пример мультипоточности: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/eca2484466a3788a67e2c787cfff2595889cdf1d/multithreading__example/example%20multiprocessing.dummy/hello_world.py Насчет, асинхронности, нагуглил пример: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/snehesht/c8ef95850c550dc47126/raw/f1e7fe23cef68b5ab24bd250a85e398af4cca791/concurrent_requests.py

Comment: Потоки нужны. Ваш пример многопоточности схож с моим, просто мы используем немного разные библиотеки. Я попробую сейчас использовать вместо robobrowser обычные запросы.

Comment: Кст, а много памяти это сколько?

Comment: она постоянно засоряется. на 100 потоках больше 4гб оперативы, и растёт дальше.

Comment: Ну не знаю, меня смущает в вашем примере 3 цикла, причем последний еще может стать бесконечным. Плюс, из-за `af.seek(0)` будет происходит "перечитывание" файла af на каждой итерации bf. Мне кажется, вам нужно оптимизировать скрипт. Кроме того, я не думаю что 100 и больше потоков оправдано, ведь для их создания тоже нужно память выделять, да и эффективность работы упадет -- каждый поток ведь будет требовать чтобы его обработали. Обычно эффективное количество потоков: количество ядер * 2

Comment: для отладки, начните с одного потока: `max_workers=1` Если память всё равно течёт (спустя какое-то время), тогда вообще уберите pool и напрямую вызывайте в цикле: `myfunc(aa, bb)` вместо `executor.submit()`. Если и это течёт (спустя какое-то время), то попробуйте зафиксировать значения `aa`, `bb`, то просто в цикле myfunc() вызывайте. Измерьте, какие именно объекты растут: [Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110259/4279)